# numpy 二次元配列データから3次元配列を生成してカラー画像にしたい

Tags: python, numpy

目的：img配列で定義された数値に応じて、color配列で定義されたRGB値を用いて、カラー画像用の三次元配列を作りたい。

以下のソースコードで、img配列の0には、color[0]=[50,80,10]を、1にはcolor[1]=[0,60,0]を代入して、カラー画像用の3次元配列を生成したいのですが、どのように記述すれば良いのか分かりません。

ご教示をお願いします。

```
import numpy as np

color = [[50,80,10],[0,60,0]]
img = [
  [0,1,0,],
  [1,1,1,],
  [0,1,0,],
]

nimg = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
```

ほしい結果

```
[
  [[50,80,10],[0,60,0],[50,80,10]],
  [[0,60,0],[0,60,0],[0,60,0],]],
  [[50,80,10],[0,60,0],[50,80,10]],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな風にできます

```py
import numpy as np

color = np.array([[50,80,10],[0,60,0]], dtype=np.uint8)
img = np.array([
  [0,1,0,],
  [1,1,1,],
  [0,1,0,],
])

nimg = color[img]
display(nimg)

assert (nimg == np.array([
  [[50,80,10],[0,60,0],[50,80,10]],
  [[0,60,0],[0,60,0],[0,60,0]],
  [[50,80,10],[0,60,0],[50,80,10]]])).all()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。color側にimgを代入するのですね。