# numpyでbitmapファイルから画像パターンデータを作るには？

Tags: python, numpy

numpyでbitmapファイルから色情報とそのドット座標を以下のように取得したいと考えています。
このケースの場合のWhereメソッドをどのように使用したらよいか分かりません。
試したソースコードでは苦肉の策として新しいリストで二次元配列を作っていますが、意図したデータになりません。

ご教示をお願いいたします。

元画像情報(3x3の画像例)

```
[
[[131,211,19,255],[0,151,0,255],[131,211,19,255],],
[[0,151,0,255],[0,151,0,255],[0,151,0,255],],
[[131,211,19,255],[0,151,0,255],[131,211,19,255],],
]
```

カラー情報の抜き取り

```
[
[131,211,19,255],
[0,151,0,255],
]
```

ドット情報(カラー情報のリストインデックス番号が座標上の色情報に置き換えられる）

```
[
[[0],[1],[0]],
[[1],[1],[1]],
[[0],[1],[0]],
]
```

試してみたソースコード

```py
import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

path = os.getcwd()+"\\image"
bmp_list = glob.glob(path+"\\*.bmp")

for f in bmp_list:
    fimg = Image.open(f)
    img_array = np.array(fimg)
    w, h, _ = img_array.shape
    color_set = set()
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            color = img_array[x][y].tolist()
            color = map(str, color)
            color = "_".join(color)
            color_set.add(color)

    array = list()

    for i, color in enumerate(color_set):
        color = color.split('_')
        color = list(map(int, color))
        for xindex in img_array:
            array.append(list())
            for c in xindex:
                if c.tolist() == color:
                    array[-1].append(i+1)
                else:
                    array[-1].append(0)
    print(array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88844/)の逆パターンということでしょうか？

`np.unique`で 座標軸の指定が可能だけど, 「row * col * 画素」 … の rowと colを同時に指定は無理なので, 「一次元 * 画素」に変換してから行う

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.array([
[[131,211,19,255],[0,151,0,255],[131,211,19,255],],
[[0,151,0,255],[0,151,0,255],[0,151,0,255],],
[[131,211,19,255],[0,151,0,255],[131,211,19,255],],
])

flat = img.reshape(-1, img.shape[-1])
cmap, inverse = np.unique(flat, axis=0, return_inverse=True)
ccode = inverse.reshape(img.shape[:-1])

# cmap   # 順序異なるけど
#array([[  0, 151,   0, 255],
#       [131, 211,  19, 255]])
# ccode
#array([[1, 0, 1],
#       [0, 0, 0],
#       [1, 0, 1]])
```

色の順序合わせたいのか不明なので, とりあえずそのままで
＆ 最終的な結果も, 質問のデータのように変換したほうがよいのか不明なのでとりあえずそのままで

---

参考:

- imageから uniqueな listを得る https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780697/numpy-unique-list-of-colors-in-the-image
- 与えられた色に等しい配列のピクセル数を見つける https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897492/finding-the-number-of-pixels-in-a-numpy-array-equal-to-a-given-color

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。前の質問の逆パターンも必要になりました。9行、10行目の構文が全く想像つきません。このようなNumpy構文をマスターするのに、良い文献やサイトはありませんでしょうか？

Comment: stackoverflow 英語版, 参考になるかと思います

Answer (score 1):

Pandas を使ってみました。

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

img = np.array([
  [[131, 211, 19, 255], [0, 151, 0, 255], [131, 211, 19, 255]],
  [[  0, 151,  0, 255], [0, 151, 0, 255], [  0, 151,  0, 255]],
  [[131, 211, 19, 255], [0, 151, 0, 255], [131, 211, 19, 255]],
])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(img).applymap(tuple)
idx, uniq = pd.factorize(df.values.ravel())
idx = idx.reshape(df.shape)
#_, uniq = pd.factorize(df.values.ravel())
#dfx = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, uniq).codes)

print(f'{uniq = }')
print(f'idx = \n{idx}')

#
uniq = array([(131, 211, 19, 255), (0, 151, 0, 255)], dtype=object)
idx = 
[[0 1 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [0 1 0]]
```

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.array([
  [[131, 211, 19, 255], [0, 151, 0, 255], [131, 211, 19, 255]],
  [[  0, 151,  0, 255], [0, 151, 0, 255], [  0, 151,  0, 255]],
  [[131, 211, 19, 255], [0, 151, 0, 255], [131, 211, 19, 255]],
])
label = np.array([[131, 211, 19, 255], [0, 151, 0, 255]])

idx = (img[...,None,:] == label).all(axis=-1)
idx = np.where(idx)[-1].reshape(img.shape[:2])[...,None]
print(idx)

#
[[[0]
  [1]
  [0]]

 [[1]
  [1]
  [1]]

 [[0]
  [1]
  [0]]]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。10,11行目img[...,None,:]などどうしてそうなるのかさっぱり分かりません。勉強します。

Comment: すみません、ユニークな pixel を取り出す処理が必要だったのですね。