# 二次元配列データを色分けする際, (所々)違う色で表示される (matplotlib - imshow)

Tags: python, python3, numpy, matplotlib

二次元データで, `np.uint8` 型の値で色分けを考えています。

- matplotlib の imshow を使用している
- `colors.ListedColormap`, `colors.BoundaryNorm` を利用予定

普段の利用にはこれで十分可能なはずが, なぜか時々 色化けが発生します
問題を再現できる中でデータを絞り込んでみた結果は 以下の通り

- 元々の shapeは 60x60 ⇨ 4x4 へ
- 20 種類の色分け ⇨ 8 種類へ
- `ListedColormap()` で色の重複があったのを重複なしへ

(以下は, 色マップと二次元データ)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['red', 'green', 'maroon', 'gray', 'Orange', 'Plum', 'lightyellow', 'Aqua'])
bounds = [0,1,3,4,13,16,48,50]+[100]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
# display(cmap)

# 色マップ: 256パターン中 100種の表示 (データは 8 種類)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
ax.imshow(a, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)   #, interpolation='nearest', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

[image: カラーマップ]

```py
# 二次元データ
arr = np.array([
 [ 3,  3, 16,  0],
 [ 3,  3, 48, 50],
 [ 1, 13, 16, 50],
 [ 1,  1,  4,  4]], dtype=np.uint8)

# データ arr を cmapに基づき色付け
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(arr, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.show()
#fig.savefig('fig1.png')
```

[image: 元のパターン]

上記のパターンを元に, 左上隅の値を変化させると,
値によっては 別の位置まで色が変わります

以下のコードでは

- 右上の図で(左上隅を 68にすると), 左下部分 1 のデータが赤で表示されてしまう
- 右下の図で(左上隅を 70にすると), 右下の部分, 4 のデータが maroon らしき色に変わる

```py
def disp_num(arr, ax):
    for r, row in enumerate(arr):
        for c, txt in enumerate(row):
            ax.text(c, r, txt, fontsize=12, ha='center', color='white')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(9, 6))
axes = ax.flatten()

for p,n in enumerate((0, 10, 68, 50, 60, 70)):
    arr[0, 0] = n
    ax = axes[p]
    ax.imshow(arr, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    disp_num(arr, ax)

plt.show()
#fig.savefig('fig2.png')
```

[image: 問題が出るパターン 一部]

#### 環境

`sys.version`
3.10.4
`matplotlib.__version__`
3.5.2

colab でも同じ現象 ('3.7.13' と '3.2.2')

#### 質問

なぜ関係ないデータの色まで変わるのでしょうか？
(指定ミスがあるのか, 使い方が間違っているのか (など))

※ 色分け自体は別アプローチで解決していて影響はないけれど, 同様の質問が出たので ついでに質問してみました
[numpy 二次元配列データから3次元配列を生成してカラー画像にしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88844/)

#### 背景

本来の(？)カラーマップならば, 10〜20, 20〜30, 30〜40 など, それぞれに幅があるかと思われ
また, 段階的に明るくなる や 青みがかるなどグラデーション的な配色で利用することが多いかなと

今回の場合, 値を色に変換する目的なため, (範囲なし)一点のみが多く, 色も唐突
それでも `BoundaryNorm` ならば対処可能かと判断しました (たぶん stackoverflow.com で見かけた Q＆Aでもそのような使い方載ってたはず)

(大抵はうまく表示されることが多いものの, ふとした拍子に色が極端に変化したので)

Comment: [Image interpolation now possible at RGBA stage](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.5.0.html#image-interpolation-now-possible-at-rgba-stage)

Comment: `interpolation_stage='rgba'` を与えることで問題出なくなった？ようですが, 先にカラーマッピングが適用される的な部分, 何か情報ないでしょうか？ それと, (理由は未だよくわからないものの) 解決してそうなので, 解答欄にお願いします